# Capturing a dataLayer value as event scoped custom dimension in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've got a dataLayer variable who's value can change with every pageview. In Universal Analytics this was tracked as a hit-scoped custom dimension and recorded via Google Tag Manager's analytics settings variable.

I'm trying to understand how to recreate this (or something similar) in GA4.

As far as I can tell, I need to create a new GA4 event that fires on every pageview and send the dataLayer value as an event parameter.

Is that right? Do you really need to fire an event ON EVERY PAGEVIEW to capture dataLayer values as custom dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

You could include this as a parameter in your GA4 configuration tag. This could allow you to capture the parameter's value on each page.  If the value could change on a single screen without moving to a new page or reloading, then you should create a new datalayer event and matching GTM trigger and tag to be sure it is captured when the value changes (rather than waiting until the next page load).

Comment: Thanks JoeL.  If this answered your question can you please mark as correct answer.  Cheers.